# Pegar o caminho do arquivo aberto pelo nome do processo em C#

Tags: c#

Tenho uma aplicação que trabalha com base no processo atual do cliente.
Estou precisando pegar o nome do arquivo e o seu caminho absoluto quando aberto. Ou seja:

Se por exemplo o cliente abrir o arquivo "teste.txt", preciso conseguir o caminho "c:\projeto\teste.txt" em vez de "c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe". O mesmo vale para .DOC, .XLS, etc...

O trecho do código abaixo retorna as informações relacionadas ao processo, que inclui o caminho do software (...\notepad.exe).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetForegroundWindow", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int GetForegroundWindow();

[...]

public static string GetFilePathName()
{
    uint procId = 0;
    int hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out procId);
    var proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)procId);
}
```

Através da classe do Processo é possível adquirir o caminho do arquivo que está sendo trabalho?

Comment: O ambiente de execução só tem informações sobre o processo, não sobre arquivos que a aplicação está manipulando. Esse contexto é da aplicação, não do processo. Que objeto você tem pra manipular o arquivo?

Answer (score 1):

## Através da classe do Processo é possível adquirir o caminho do arquivo que está sendo trabalho?

Não. Para este caso, a abordagem precisa ser outra, usando uma classe do .NET chamada [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). [Retirei daqui o exemplo abaixo](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/article.php/c6043/Using-FileSystemWatcher.htm):

```
m_starting_path.Text = "C:\\
watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

//---------------------------------------------------------------
// Suponho que seja uma aplicação que tenha um botão
// Aqui ocorre o acionamento do FileSystemWatcher, que 
// funciona basicamente com eventos. 

private void MeuBotaoClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (watcher.EnableRaisingEvents == true) {
        MessageBeep(100);
        return
    }

    watcher.Path         = m_starting_path.Text;
    watcher.Filter       = m_filter.Text;
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName |
                           NotifyFilters.Attributes |
                           NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                           NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                           NotifyFilters.Security |
                           NotifyFilters.Size;


    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnFileEvent);
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnFileEvent);
    watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnFileEvent);
    watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenameEvent);
    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

public void OnFileEvent(object source, FileSystemEventArgs fsea)
{
    // Aqui você verifica modificações no arquivo (source)
}

public void OnRenameEvent(Object source, RenamedEventArgs rea)
{
    // Aqui você verifica arquivos renomeados
}
```

Pra relacionar o processo ao arquivo, [você pode usar uma das soluções propostas nesta pergunta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-using-net).

Comment: Cigano, neste caso a minha aplicação captura automaticamente o processo que está sendo executado. Por exemplo: se eu estou com o Notepad aberto alterando o arquivo "Teste.txt", ele captura esse evento. O que eu preciso é capturar também o Path do arquivo "Teste.txt" neste exato momento.

Comment: Pois então, pra você pegar o path você usa a primeira parte da questão. Pra relacionar o Handle com o arquivo, o link do SO. Qual a dúvida?